# AWS Cognito & next-auth@5.0.0.beta custom authorization

Tags: next.js, amazon-cognito, next-auth

it's several weeks I am trying to implement custom authorization using credentials/social providers with aws cognito and next-auth but still no result ... if someone has experience with new nextjs and next-auth please help ... this is my provider options:

```js
function getProvider(provider: TProvider) {
  return {
    id: `cognito_${provider.toLowerCase()}`,
    name: `Cognito${provider}`,
    type: 'oauth',
    issuer: COGNITO_ISSUER!,
    clientId: COGNITO_CLIENT_ID!,
    clientSecret: COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    wellKnown: `https://cognito-idp.${COGNITO_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
    authorization: {
      url: `${COGNITO_DOMAIN}/oauth2/authorize`,
      params: {
        response_type: 'code',
        client_id: COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        identity_provider: provider,
        redirect_uri: `${NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/auth/callback/cognito_${provider.toLowerCase()}`,
        scope: 'openid',
      },
    },
    token: {
      url: `${COGNITO_DOMAIN}/oauth2/token`,
      params: {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirect_uri: `${NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/auth/callback/cognito_${provider.toLowerCase()}`,
        scope: 'openid',
      },
    },
    userinfo: {
      url: `${COGNITO_DOMAIN}/oauth2/userInfo`,
    },
    profile: function (profile: any) {
      console.log('is it heeere?');
      return {
        id: profile.sub,
        ...profile,
      };
    },
  };
}
```

user is created, I have data in cognito, but when it redirects to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/cognito_google there happens error, i have created custom GET methods to check if code is created, tried to sign in manually, looks like this:

```js
export const GET = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url as string | URL);
  const code = searchParams.get('code');

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN}/oauth2/token?code=${code}`,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
          client_id: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID!,
          client_secret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET!,
          grant_type: 'refresh_token',
          code,
          //   refresh_token: token.refreshToken
        }),
        method: 'POST',
      },
    );

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('data', data);

    console.log('responseresponseresponse', response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('MY ERROR', err);
  }

  console.log('code', code);

  return res.json({ code });
};
```

and i get error for that fetch request: Bad Request

inside cognito I have checked "**Authorization code grant**"
**OpenID Connect scopesInfo**: Email, OpenId, Phone

if i do not edit api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts file and it looks like this:

```js
import { handlers } from '@/auth/auth';

export const { GET, POST } = handlers;
```

**i have error: unsapported_grant_type**

but user is created :| any idea?

I have also checked generate a client secret while creating user pool